# Using the POST URI in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, get, uri

I am trying to post data into a website that takes text data through the URL: `"http://data.bioontology.org/annotator?text=" + theTextData`

I want to use a POST URI to get the data. Here is my code:

```
def get_annotations(text, url):
    headers = [('Authorization', 'apikey token=' + API_KEY)]
    data = text

    response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=data)
    return response.text.encode('utf-8')

annotations = get_annotations(text, "http://data.bioontology.org/annotator?text=" + urllib.parse.quote(text))
```

I get this error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
    response = requests.request("POST",url,headers=headers,data=data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 516, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 449, in prepare_request
    p.prepare(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 315, in prepare
    self.prepare_headers(headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 447, in prepare_headers
    for header in headers.items():
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'
```

How do I fix this? Am I using POST incorrectly?

Comment: I'm guessing you're using ```import requests```.  first - You do not need a post request, you need a get request. Second - use ```requests.get()```

Comment: @Babydesta My data is too long, so if I use a get URI I will get an HTTP 414 error

Answer (score 0):

Your headers should be a dict, not a tuple in a list.

```py
headers = {'Authorization': 'apikey token=' + API_KEY}
```